# No networking after reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot, graphics

After installing a new graphics card (Radeon R9 380X) on my 970A-D3P board I had difficulty starting Ubuntu. The system was duel boot and I could log into windows. After resetting BIOS I could log onto Ubuntu (though still had some problems) but windows would crash. I have since done a complete reinstall attempting to make another dual boot windows 8.1 with Ubuntu. I had difficulty getting any start disk (DVD or USB) to work but finally managed to get Ubuntu installed after resetting BIOS. However, I now have no wifi (it detects networks but I cannot log on) or wired network.

Networking (wired and unwired) works in Windows.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system (mobo GA-990FXA-UD5 R5 I needed to add "iommu=soft" to the grub config file under GRUB_CMDLINE=

there is a thread floating around somewhere about it, but this should resolve the issue with USB and networking ports working oddly.  For the life of me I cannot find the source post of this :/

Also, if you have issues booting a live USB, you can edit the grub entry to boot the live/installer to have `iommu=soft` in the grub line for the /boot/..... Info.  Access the built-in grub editor by pressing e on the grub menu.

Edit: just found a source with clearer instructions: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=4

Edit2: for clarity:  the AMD 900series seems to sometimes have odd behaving USB and onboard NIC issues which occur due to iommu implementation.  This should resolve those issues.

Comment: Hi, do you mean /etc/default/grub  ?

Comment: Yes, but for booting the install media, I needed to enable iommu=soft to properly boot the install material.  The GRUB_CMDLINE is for editing the grub config you mentioned.

Comment: sorry this is new to me. Do you mean the line  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` should be edited to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"`

Comment: @ultrakow Exactly.  Save it, then from cmd line, run 'sudo update-grub'

Comment: Just updated the answer with a source that is similar to the one I followed.  I did leave iommu enabled in BIOS though.  It seems the source says to disable it after.  Think that may be optional.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly. I had issues (system crashes) in windows when i enabled IOMMU in BIOS (Legacy mode). Anyhow cheers mate!

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped.  Took me a while to find the info when I first installed Debian testing.  Lost network connection when loading installer, and that's a HUGE problem for a network installer :)

Answer (score 0):

Open up your Terminal and try this : *sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer*

I had the same problem and it worked for me. Tell me if it works

Banana out

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That did not work sadly. I get "unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer".  I have no networking at all in Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you try to just restart your router if you're using wifi.  Just checking

Comment: yeah I restarted. Just wont log on.